# CSS3 framework, creating center content area with designated height

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I know the very basics of CSS and recently went on with using CSS frameworks because it made my life much easier. I have a question in terms of grid systems, am currently using zurb foundation 3 (http://foundation.zurb.com/)

The problem am facing is mostly when creating a row i cannot give it a specific height. It seems to me like grid systems are designed to use as it is, I read in different places that it is not recommended to try and change the height of a row and to just place items inside it as it is.

In my project, I have a content area whereby I want to display a fixed height and width div but its not working for me. so, can any one advise me what should i do? below is my html code

update: edited the html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
    <div style="height:6em; width:5em;>
          <!-- my block -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six columns">
    <div style="height:6em; width:5em;>
          <!-- my block -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using "=" instead of ":"

Comment: yes write "height:6em;width:5em" not height=6em

Answer (score 1):

Your 'style' declarations are wrong

```
style="height=6em; width:5em;
```

should be

```
style="height:6em; width:5em;"
```

NOTE: you used = instead of : AND you missed the closing quotation "

And you should not use inline styles - separate to a .css file and target them by class

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/foundation3/stylesheets/foundation.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
    <div style="height:6em; width:5em;">
          <!-- my block -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six columns">
    <div style="height:6em; width:5em;">
          <!-- my block -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I have not declared a DOCTYPE here - this is barebones. It does work I have tested it in Firefox and Chrome. Just stating it does not work is not helpful OP

Comment: sorry it was a typo in my code. even when i changed it from = to : am setting getting the same result